# htaccess specify path for file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a RewriteRule in an .htaccess file where, when a user tries to access: `mp.php?id=2` the URL is rewritten to `/private/items/mp.php?id=2`

I tried different variations, based on this page: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php  The most recent of which is:

```
RewriteRule ^mp.php/(.*) /%1/private/items/mp.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Which, doesn't appear to work, although, I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteRule does not match in query strings, and can copy the query string to the rewriten path, so you only have to do this:

```
RewriteRule ^mp\.php /private/items/mp.php [QSA]
```

Which will result in `mp.php?id=42` being rewritten to `/private/items/mp.php?id=42`